# Change link color on hover javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change a certain on hover over another certain item.

For example:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">test</a>
</li>
```

JS

```
var list = document.getElementById('li');
var link = document.getElementById('a');

list.onmouseover = function() {
    link.style.color = "#8080ff";
}
```

If i hover over the `li` item I want the text inside the `a` tag to change, but this code is not working.

I cant use css or jquery library.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nt8Pq/40/

Comment: Why can't you use CSS? Also, I recommend using event listeners.

Comment: Those are not `id`s, those are element-types. If JavaScript doesn't work then the first recourse is to Google the methods you're using to try and find out *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's really complicated to explain.

Comment: CSS is shorter and faster, read about `:hover` selector. You can toggle a class on the node if you really must.

Comment: The code does not work because there is no element with an id "li" and not element with an id "a"

Comment: @epascarello getElementByTagName doesn't work either

Comment: because getElementsByTagName returns an HTML collection. HTML collections do not work like a single element. You would need to loop over the collection

Comment: `getElementByTagName` doesn't exist. The function name has a `s` in the middle of it.

Comment: You could use. `var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];` But that will get all anchor tags. And `onmouseover ` will change the color. But it won't change back. http://jsfiddle.net/Nt8Pq/43/ So you will have to figure those parts out as well..

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck that helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks for elements with ids and you have not ids. You would need to select them by the tag name and loop over the collection. And than you would need to find the anchor that is inside of the collection.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var lis = menu.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  var li = lis[i];
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#8080ff";
  });
  li.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    this.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "#000000";
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the end this is a lot of code to implement

```
ul li:hover a {
    color : "#8080ff";
}
```

SO you could just inject a CSS rule if you are not able to actually add styles to the page...

```js
var sheet = window.document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.insertRule('#menu li:hover a { color: #8080ff; }', sheet.cssRules.length);
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's cool. I didn't know you could insert a rule into a sheet like that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with some simple HTML event attributes and JavaScript.

```
<li>
<a href="#" onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.style.color='blue'">test</a>
</li>
```

[HTML Event Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with JS, here is the answer. But like said before, you shouldn't do it this way:

```
<li id="list">
<a id="link" href="#">test</a>
</li>

 var list = document.getElementById('list');
 var link = document.getElementById('link');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nt8Pq/45/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can not modify the CSS or the source of the web page, and you are stuck only with a single javascript file in which you wish to modify some features of a web page, then this approach will work:

One caveat is you have to use of an index in `document.getElementsByTagName('li')` which returns an array. If you always need the first element for example, you can hard code this index as zero. Otherwise, you need to iterate over the collection looking for the one you wish to change.

Finally, you can modify the style of the `firstChildElement` after you find the list item you want.

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];

li.onmouseover = function() {
  li.firstElementChild.style.color = "#F00"; // red
}

li.onmouseout = function() {
  li.firstElementChild.style.color = "#000"; // black
};
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">Mouse over me.</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodesArray = document.getElementById('myID').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < nodesArray.length; i++) {
    nodesArray[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

May be you will find your solution in this link:-https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692280